# Using negative margins to make a block-level element sit outside it's content area

Tags: html, css, mobile, margin

I need to make a block-level element sit outside it's content area. The content area has a margin round it of 10px; which means that (as expected) the items within sit with a 10px edge around them. I need to eradicate this edge, but keep the 10px margin (as it's needed elsewhere on the site.)

I've put together a [colour-coded JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SxbZe/) to help which makes a lot more sense. Essentially, keeping the HTML and the CSS for the margins as they are, I need my red h2's to expand to touch either edge of the viewport, as though they were 100%.

How can this be acheived? I know that using negative margins is possible but I cannot seem to make it work.

```
<div class="contentMain">
<div class="mobCategory">
    <h2><a href="#">Item one</a></h2>
    <h2><a href="#">Item two</a></h2>
    <h2><a href="#">Item three</a></h2>
</div>
```

```
body{
        background-color:orange;
    }
    .contentMain{
        background-color:olive;
        margin:10px;
    }

    .mobCategory h2 a{
        background-color:red;
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the negative margins to your h2:

http://jsfiddle.net/SxbZe/6/ (note that the body has had its margin set to 0)

```
.mobCategory h2 {
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}
```

Comment: Ah awesome, I was under the impression that the `margin-right` in this example would override the `margin-left`. Nice, simple solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can kind of hack it by adding negative margin and padding to counter the difference:

```
.mobCategory h2 a {
    margin-left: -10px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/SxbZe/2/).